# How to prevent application logs getting logged in server.log in Wildfly 8.2.0 Final AS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, wildfly-8

I am migrating an EAR application from **JBoss 6.1.0 AS** to **Wildfly 8.2.0 AS**. EAR contains **log4j.xml** and application logs are generated by using this logging configuration file by employing the below line of code:

*org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(log4j file path)*

Application logs are generated fine but in server.log, application logs are also getting appended. I am using **standalone-full-ha.xml** configuration file and tried the below steps:

1. Added jboss-deployment-structure.xml with the following contents:

```
<deployment>

     <exclude-subsystems>

    <subsystem name="logging" />

 </exclude-subsystems>

</deployment>
```

2. Added below lines under `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">` section

in **standalone-full-ha.xml**.

```
<use-deployment-logging-config value="true"/>

<add-logging-api-dependencies value="false"/>
```

How can I prevent applications logs getting appended in server.log ? Please help.

**Workaround tried**

Just adding to my previous comments, I tried first option provided in the link http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-log/using-log4j-with-jboss-as-7-and-wildfly.

1. Added log4j.xml under META-INF of EAR.
2. Added org.apache.log4j module as one of the dependencies attribute in MANIFEST.MF.
3. It was mentioned to add a VM argument -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=true but I did not add.

server.log is generated fine and application logs are getting generated fine but I have below concerns:

1. is the starting tag in log4j.xml and it has "warn" as value of threshold attribute. But, I am getting all kind of logs (i.e. works as ALL or DEBUG threshold).
2. I have placed log4j.xml in META-INF of EAR. So, will org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(log4j file path) work where path denotes log4j.xml in META-INF ? Default time out is 60 seconds and if I change threshold, will it reflect ?

Answer (score 1):

I use following jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/master/server/src/main/resources/schema/jboss-deployment-structure-1_2.xsd-->
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
       <exclude-subsystems>
           <subsystem name="logging"/>
       </exclude-subsystems>
      <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j.impl"/>
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
```

Comment: many thanks for the response .. sibnick. If log4j dependencies are excluded in jboss-deployment-structure.xml, then should log4j jar be added within EAR ? I was referring log4j module in dependencies classpath of EAR.

Comment: Yes you should include it to your application (war or ear).

Comment: many thanks.. sibnick. Adding 1. <add-logging-api-dependencies value="false"/>, <use-deployment-logging-config value="true"/> and 2. log4j.jar under lib folder of EAR ensured application logs are not getting appended in server.log. But, am getting below error

Comment: ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.test.util.logging.LogFactory).

ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: I have @startup EJBs logging some information in application logs and following per-deployment logging stopped logging those startup information. Is this because of the first issue as log4j is not configured well initially.

Comment: I have added a "workaround tried" section in my blog. Could you please check whether you have faced the same. Many thanks.

Comment: You need redeploy application if you change log4j.xml inside ear. It is big disadvantage of putting log4j.xml to META-INF. Actually in my project I use log4j2 and totaly switch off log4j for my app. You can use "Logging Profiles" as described here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-LoggingProfiles